# Issue inserting a ContactShare object with Database.SaveResult

Tags: apex, soql, dml

I need to insert a new ContactShare object in apex. Here is a sample of the code I have :

```
Map<String, Id> mapUserRole = new Map<String, Id>();
    for(UserRole ur : lRoles){
        mapUserRole.put(ur.Name, ur.Id);
    }
List<ContactShare> lContactShareToInsert = new List<ContactShare>(); 

for(Mission__c mission : lMissions){
    for(Contact con : lContacts){
                    if(mission.box__c != con.box__c && mapUserRole.get(mission.box__c) != null){

                        //créer contactShare
                        ContactShare conShare = new ContactShare();
                        conShare.ContactAccessLevel = 'Read';
                        conShare.ContactId = con.Id; 
                        conShare.UserOrGroupId =  mapUserRole.get(mission.box__c);

                        System.debug('### conShare : ' + conShare);

                        lContactShareToInsert.add(conShare);

                        System.debug('### lContactShareToInsert : ' + lContactShareToInsert);
                    }
                }
             }

 Database.SaveResult[] srContactShare = Database.insert(lContactShareToInsert, false);

    for(Database.SaveResult srS : srContactShare){
        System.debug('### srS : ' + srS);
        if(srS.isSuccess()){
            System.debug('### srContactShare is insert');
        }
    }
```

The problem is that I got an error in the debug of srS, so the list of contactShare to insert is not insert because it is not successfill :

> #### srS : Database.SaveResult[getErrors=(Database.Error[getFields=(UserOrGroupId);getMessage=User/Group ID: id value of incorrect type: 00E4E000000Xfj4UAC;getStatusCode=FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION;]);getId=null;isSuccess=false;]

Comment: Make your apex class  "without sharing" and then try!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the [User, Sharing, and Permission Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_users.htm) ERD copied below, you will have to identify a single `User` object that references a selected `UserRole` and use the `Id` of that in `conShare.UserOrGroupId`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Refer [Sharing a Record Using Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_bulk_sharing_creating_with_apex.htm)

`UserOrGroupId` should be either userId or public group id.

According to your code, it is `UserRoleId`, thats why it is invalid value.

You can create a public group based on the role and use that public group id for sharing the record.